# How to prevent notification permission when I launch first time?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a special button that requesting a permission to allow notification but I see the permission before I clicking the button. Does anybody know how to disable it?

Thank you!

Comment: Share code solution that you implment

Comment: Execute the code on touchUpInside of button instead of didFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using in AppDelegate.swift

```
        alarmScheduler.setupNotificationSettings()
    window?.tintColor = UIColor.red

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: .alert, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

So I just deleted it and resolved my trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea, **Untested** with controller

Call **UIApplicationDelegate** In your **viewcontroller**

In **Button Action**,

```
registerForRemoteNotification()

func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

And implement follow delegates,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
    {
}
```